# Create Folder on Home Screen where i can put some icons in grid

Tags: widget, directory, homescreen, android-livefolders

In Android i want to make **folder on home screen** programmatically like  **clean master do for game booster** and also Google put its all application in one folder.
I try with Live folder but its deprecated and also not working for me in latest android version.

Is it a widget or what i can't understand about this please help me to understand this.
Thanks in advance